# Getting name of parameterized class in scala using shapeless

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I want to get the name of a class passed as a parameter to a function using shapeless. I've tried this:

```
def sayMyName[T](t: T): String = Typeable[T].describe // error: class type required but T found
```

If `T` is replaced with a concrete type, there's no problem. Is it possible to make something like this work using shapeless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `Typeable` typeclass as context bound of your type `T`:

```
def sayMyName[T: Typeable](t: T): String = Typeable[T].describe

sayMyName("") //String
```

You could also explicitly declare implicit parameter:

```
def sayMyName[T](t: T)(implicit typeable: Typeable[T]): String = Typeable[T].describe
```

By adding context bound you're asking the compiler to wait with resolving `Typeable`
typeclass until `sayMyName` is called with the concrete type, not resolve it right away (which is impossible, since the real type of T is not yet known at this point).